# Adding max and min in spark stream in JAVA?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to add max and min to each RDD in a spark dstream..each of it's tuple. I wrote the following code, but can't understand how to pass the parameter min and max.
Can anyone suggest a way to do this transformation?
I tried the following:

```
JavaPairDStream<Tuple2<Long, Integer>, Tuple3<Integer,Long,Long>> sortedtsStream = transformedMaxMintsStream.transformToPair(new Sort2());

class MinMax implements Function<JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Long, Integer>, Integer>, JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Long, Integer>, Tuple3<Integer, Long, Long>>>{
    Long max;
    Long min;
    @Override
    public JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Long, Integer>, Tuple3<Integer, Long, Long>> call(JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Long, Integer>, Integer> input) throws Exception {
        JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Long,Integer>,Tuple3<Integer,Long,Long>> output;
        max = input.max(new CMP1())._1._1;
        min = input.min(new CMP1())._1._1;
        output = input.mapToPair(new maptoMinMax());
        return output   ;
    }
    class maptoMinMax implements PairFunction<Tuple2<Tuple2<Long, Integer>, Integer>, Tuple2<Long, Integer>, Tuple3<Integer, Long, Long>> {

        @Override
        public Tuple2<Tuple2<Long, Integer>, Tuple3<Integer, Long, Long>> call(Tuple2<Tuple2<Long, Integer>, Integer> tuple2IntegerTuple2) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2<Tuple2<Long, Integer>, Tuple3<Integer, Long, Long>>(new Tuple2<Long, Integer>(tuple2IntegerTuple2._1._1,tuple2IntegerTuple2._1._2), new Tuple3<Integer, Long, Long>(tuple2IntegerTuple2._2, max,min));
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error: Essentially seems like min and max functions for JavaPairRDD were not found

```
15/06/18 11:05:06 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1434639906000 in memory on localhost:42829 (size: 464.0 KB, free: 264.9 MB)
15/06/18 11:05:06 INFO BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1434639906000
Exception in thread "JobGenerator" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.max(Ljava/util/Comparator;)Lscala/Tuple2;
        at org.necla.ngla.spark_streaming.MinMax.call(Type4ViolationChecker.java:346)
        at org.necla.ngla.spark_streaming.MinMax.call(Type4ViolationChecker.java:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$class.scalaTransform$3(JavaDStreamLike.scala:360)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$transformToPair$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$transformToPair$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$transform$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(DStream.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$transform$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(DStream.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$transform$2$$anonfun$5.apply(DStream.scala:668)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$transform$2$$anonfun$5.apply(DStream.scala:666)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.compute(TransformedDStream.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStrea
```

Comment: What's the intention of having max/min for each tuple? does that mean that a stream line: 1 3 5 4 2 gets transformed to (1,1,1), (3,3,1), (5, 5, 1),(4,5,1),(2,5,1) ??  What would be the use of that?  (See how pretty soon the data becomes repetitive and therefore overhead) - I'm wondering whether the actual question is "how to calculate stateful min/max for (rdd or  dstreams)"

Comment: I am trying to identify the last and first and last key,value pair in a RDD after I have sorted the dstream by timestamp.. here max and min are actually timestamps.

Comment: Also correct me if I am wrong, the min and max will be min max for the entire RDD. Hence in your example I will get (1,5,1), (3,5,1), (5,5,1) assuming they are in the same RDD. Isn't that right?

Comment: So the intention is to get the record with the min and max timestamps per RDD for each batch interval? and we assume records come in no particular order, right?

Comment: yes.. I was able to successfully sort the records using the timestamps within the messages. However, I am unable to use foreachRDD, to get min and max of each RDD in every batch

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rdd.transform` to apply several operations on the same RDD to come to our result for each batch interval. We will add this result to each tuple (as per question spec)

```
data.transform{rdd => 
     val mx = rdd.map(x=> (x,x)).reduce{case ((x1,x2),(y1,y2)) => ((x1 min y1), (x2 max y2))}
     rdd.map(elem => (elem,mx))                              
}
```

This produces an RDD each block interval like (random numbers between 1 and 999 incl):

> (258,(0,998)) (591,(0,998)) ...

Java version is semantically identical but quite more verbose due to all those Tuple<...> objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I believe it is technically correct and I tried to implement the same in Java, but I get a run-time error saying that the min and max functions were not found. I am using spark-1.4. Any way you can suggest how I can fix this?

Comment: I have added the error and the code in Java in my question.. If you can please have a look :)

Comment: Min and max operations are simple numeric ops. In javs it is Math.max(x,y)